# I'm looking for an easy way about Package Compatibility: So, because flutterapp depends on both 〇〇 and 〇〇 version solving failed

Tags: flutter

I upgraded Flutter, and while modifying pubspec.yaml to make the code support null safety, I got the following error.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...                     
    Because cached_network_image >=3.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_cache_manager ^3.0.0-nullsafety and no versions of flutter_cache_manager match >=3.0.0-nullsafety <3.0.0-nullsafety.0, cached_network_image >=3.0.0-nullsafety requires flutter_cache_manager ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0.

(1) So, because flutter_cache_manager >=3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on path_provider ^2.0.0, cached_network_image >=3.0.0-nullsafety requires path_provider ^2.0.0.



    Because no versions of flutter_camera_ml_vision match >2.3.0 <3.0.0 and flutter_camera_ml_vision >=2.2.3 <2.2.5 depends on path_provider ^1.4.0, flutter_camera_ml_vision >=2.2.3 <2.2.5-∞ or >2.3.0 <3.0.0 requires path_provider ^1.4.0.

    And because flutter_camera_ml_vision >=2.2.5 <2.3.0 depends on path_provider ^1.6.0 and flutter_camera_ml_vision 2.3.0 depends on path_provider ^1.6.18, flutter_camera_ml_vision ^2.2.3 requires path_provider ^1.4.0.

    And because cached_network_image >=3.0.0-nullsafety requires path_provider ^2.0.0 (1), cached_network_image >=3.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with flutter_camera_ml_vision ^2.2.3.

    So, because flutterapp depends on both flutter_camera_ml_vision ^2.2.4 and cached_network_image ^3.0.0-nullsafety, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1;     So, because flutterapp depends on both flutter_camera_ml_vision ^2.2.4 and cached_network_image ^3.0.0-nullsafety, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

In addition to this, I also get an error saying that the version of path_provider used by the package is different and therefore incompatible.
If I want to use null safety without waiting for the package to support null safety, do I have to modify all the packages that use path_provider to make them compatible?
I would like to use null safety if possible, so I would like to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'any' instead of using version number.
Eg: cached_network_image: any

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: any issues using this for the project moving forward